# Relative pathing

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Creating a wordpress sight for work to display some info. For convience i have included the following php code

```
<?php include 'wp-includes/fancyboxstart.php'; ?>
```

that file loads all the JS, and defines the div id for my fancybox img display. Recently i have changed the permalinks on my WordPress to get rid of the awful page=1 html links. Now i know to fix all my images simply by adding a "/" to the front on my img srcs. My problem is now that i have changed the permalinks it is no longer loading the JS page from above and my Image displayer no longer works =[

I have tried directly linking to it with

```
`<?php include 'http://premiumshotguns.com/wp-includes/fancyboxstart.php'; ?>`
```

but no luck. I know it's probably a simple fix but i am not seeing it! any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `include 'http://premiumshotguns...`: You don't include source files with `HTTP`

Comment: yeah, i know it throws errors every time. I did that as a last ditch effort. The only way it doesn't throw a error is if i just leave it as <?php include 'wp-includes/fancyboxstart.php'; ?> but then the page never laods

Comment: I have figured it out! I stepped away for lunch and then while eating i remembered i'm am a silly coder and for got to make all my links inside the php page im calling absolute. Sometimes you just need to step away i suppose

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to include your theme path.

```
<?php include bloginfo('template_directory').'/wp-includes/fancyboxstart.php'; ?>
```